# Why is there always a red paragraph in all Informs templates?

Tags: templates

Why is there always a red paragraph in all Informs templates?

Can I edit or delete the red paragraph? Or should I submit my manuscript with the red paragraph?

The first line in the tex file is 
`\documentclass[orsc,nonblindrev]{informs3}`,

where `orsc` is the abbreviation of "organization science(a journal of Informs)".

[image]

Comment: Because the editorial board decided to added this disclaimer by default. The red text as well as the two other lines above it are controlled by `\theARTICLETOP` (see `informs3.cls` file for the definition).

Comment: Thanks! So...how can I edit a cls file?

Comment: @fuyangZhao You don't. The journal decided that this is shown at that stage of writing. Period.

Comment: Don't edit the `.cls` file. You can make the changes in your `.tex` file. Copy the original definition of the command in the premble of your `.tex` file and make there the required changes. Notice, however, that the journal specifically required this option and that the template is to be used only for submissions to these journals with thos requirements. It's better not to change it.

Comment: Leave it alone for the submission, the staff will remove it. If, for distributing your preprint (assuming you're allowed to), you don't want the red warning, just add `\renewcommand{\theARTICLETOP}{}` just before `\begin{document}`, but remember to remove the command for the submission!

Comment: @egreg: Write it up! :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The disclaimer that's printed in red on top of the page explicitly disallows using the template for other purposes than submission to an INFORMS journal:

> INFORMS journal templates are for the exclusive purpose of submitting to an INFORMS journal and should not be used to distribute the papers in print or online or to submit the papers to another publication.

So leave it as it stands and don't tamper with it.

If you're annoyed by the flashing red warning (and I understand you are), just add

```
\renewcommand{\theARTICLETOP}{}
```

before `\begin{document}`, but remember to remove it before submitting the paper. And, please, comply with the notice and *do not* distribute preprints made with the template.

Comment: Do you know how to remove the line right underneath the keywords (I believe the line is created by \hfill, but I cannot find it in the `.cls` file), as well as the line at the top of the page and every small stuffs on the top of those lines appearing on every pages from page 2?

Comment: @user177196 Try with `\ARTICLERULE{}` in the document preamble.

Comment: Thank you so much. It eliminates the line underneath the Keywords, but the line at the top of every pages since page 2 still appears (as well as the small letterhead right above that line on the top right corner). How do we remove those things?

Comment: If I want to change the small text on the top right corner right above those top lines on the 2nd page on-wards, do you know how we can do it? Really appreciate any help you can offer.

Comment: @user177196 Sorry, but I don't understand: the class should only be used for submitting papers to INFORMS. And they want preprints with the formatting they provide.

Comment: I think I found the answer :) I need to re-format my paper to upload it onto places like Arxiv or SSRN. Thank you for your help.